# How to handle external events in CQRS?

Tags: domain-driven-design, integration, cqrs

Supposed I have a CQRS-based system with a web UI that I want to integrate with some external device, let's say an Arduino board.

Basically, I can think of three scenarios:

1. When the user clicks on a button in the web UI, the Arduino shall do something.
2. When the user pushes a hardware button, the domain shall react and the UI shall update.
3. When the user pushes a hardware button, the UI shall update.

How do I model these scenarios?

1. This is quite easy IMHO: UI emits a command, business logic runs, emits an event, and Arduino is listening for events. Basically, the Arduino is nothing but an event denormalizer. Is this the correct approach?
2. This is quite easy IMHO as well: Arduino emits a command, sends it to the command bus, and the same procedure runs as with scenario 1. Basically, there's no difference for the CQRS-system whether the command comes from the web UI of from anything else.
3. This is where I'm really unsure: Supposed the Arduino handles the button press itself, and flashes an LED in response. I just want to make sure that my application takes notice of "the LED has been flashing". This is no command (as the flashing already happened), instead it's an event. What do I do with this event? Do I simply store it in the event store and bypass my domain? This seems horribly wrong to me. Do I emit a pseudo-command which is turned 1:1 into a matching event? This will work and does not bypass the domain, but it feels wrong as well, as it actually is no command. What should I do?

Any advice on these things?

Comment: Can you say more about your read/write model (same, different...) ? One approach can be after treating command... Dernormlize the result in read model (read model of Arduino board) and send it (or ask for it)

Answer (score 0):

1.Just use an event handler( updating ui maybe using websocket ) listening on Arduino event if no state should change in your domain.
2. Use a saga listening on Arduino event and fire a command if state should change in your domain.

UI is not a domain concern. So I prefer option 1.